# Arduino - Expected Unqualified-id

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am trying to write code for an alarm for my Middle School project, and am using Arduino. For this to work, I needed the keypad library, and so imported that, and used the set-up code that was provided on the website.

When I go to verify the code, it comes up with the error message as stated in the title:

```
Alarm.ino:5:1: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

As far as I understand, the error lies on line 5, which looks like this:

```
const byte cols = 3; //three columns
```

The previous line ends like this:

```
const byte rows = 4; //four rows
```

What do I need to change to get the code to work?

Comment: The paragraph in question looks as follows:
    http://pastebin.com/VfkPNu1c

Comment: Does this work: `char keys[4][3] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'#','0','*'}
};`? You can then use `sizeof()` to get the `rows` and `cols` values

Comment: Perhaps `byte` is not defined. Try replacing it with `int`.

Comment: Thanks. You've done it @jayjay!

Comment: Which language is it? C or C++? Pick one tag accordingly. Also, better post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out below, this applies to C not C++:

Arrays need a size that is a *constant expression*, making something `const` does not meet that criteria.

```
char keys[4][3] = {
    {'1','2','3'},
    {'4','5','6'},
    {'7','8','9'},
    {'#','0','*'}
};
```

Comment: What you say is not true for C++.

Comment: True... didn't notice the cpp tag, modified accordingly.